# Airflow-Trigger job using python script

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have list of dags based on categories. These dags should be called from master dag based on priority of categories(to avoid resource constraint).

My thought is to create a python script, where these category dags should be triggered based on priority(not time based) which we set in metadata table. This python script will be called in master dag using bashoperator.

To be clear, Master dag should be time based. Sub dags should be triggered from master based on priority.

My questions are..

1)Is dag can be triggered using python? without time based.
2)I want to run few category dags in parallel. How this can be accomplished. Kindly help me to fix this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `TriggerDagRunOperator` and set `priority_weight` on each task that uses `TriggerDagRunOperator` to achieve that.

> [TriggerDagRunOperator](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/airflow/operators/dagrun_operator.html?highlight=TriggerDagRunOperator): Triggers a DAG run for a specified `dag_id`
>
> [priority_weight](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_api/airflow/models/baseoperator/index.html#airflow.models.baseoperator.BaseOperator) (int) – priority weight of this task against other task. This allows the executor to trigger higher priority tasks before others when things get backed up. Set priority_weight as a higher number for more important tasks.